# python list to dataframe object

Tags: pandas

When I try to convert the list to pandas dataframe, I get the entire line as a single cell.

```
pdlist=['From: 2012-11-07 19:16:07, To: 2012-11-07 19:21:07, Downtime: 0h 05m 00s',
 'From: 2012-11-13 06:16:07, To: 2012-11-13 06:21:07, Downtime: 0h 05m 00s',
 'From: 201=4-10-19 18:10:57, To: 2014-10-19 18:25:57, Downtime: 0h 15m ']

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(pdlist)
```

Expected output would be 3 columns with the first 2 being date-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to split the items on the basis of commas . Here's a method:

```
  pdlist2=[]
  for item in pdlist:
      pdlist2.append(item.split(','))
  pd.DataFrame(pdlist2)
```

Using list comprehensions :

```
pdlist2 = [item.split(',') for item in pdlist]
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pdlist2)
```

**Update:**
Since you need 3 different columns without `"from:"` `"To:"` and `"Downtime:"` , this should work. This isn't the best method but does the job.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
dict2={'From':[],'To':[],'Downtime':[]} #initialize dictionary with keys and empty values
for item in pdlist2:
    a=re.sub('From: ','',item[0]) #remove From:
    dict2['From'].append(a)
    b = re.sub('To: ','',item[1]) #remove To:
    dict2['To'].append(b)
    c = re.sub('Downtime: ','',item[2]) #remove Downtime
    dict2['Downtime'].append(c)
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dict2) #Convert dict to dataframe with dict keys as column names.
```

**Note:** The `re.sub` expression will work if all observations start the same way .

In case you want it in the order "From" ,"To" ,"Downtime" ,  you can do:

```
my_dataframe_new= my_dataframe[['From','To','Downtime']]
```